# Hibernate Model , One to Many using Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to work with Hibernate and I am not very sure how to solve this problem, I have 2 tables with a 1..n relationship like this:

```
-------
TABLE_A
-------
col_id (pk)
col_key (pk)
[other fields]

-------
TABLE_B
-------
col_id (pk) (fk TABLE_A.col_id)
col_key (pk) 
col_parentkey      (fk TABLE_A.col_key)
[other fields]

TABLE_A is one to many relation with TABLE_B.

TABLE_A.id and TABLE_A.key are primary key (composite key).
TABLE_B.id and TABLE_B.key are primary key (composite key).
```

At the same time TABLE_B.parentkey is same as TABLE_A.key and TABLE_B.id is same as TABLE_A.id

How can I manage this with Hibernate?

I do not have any idea how to declare a foreign key that would contain a part of primary key.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: How i can implement using hibernate embeddeid

Comment: *My database schema is generated from the Hibernate model.*: then you have already modeled the entities using Hibernate, haven't you? If you're free to generate the schema the way you want to, why don't you generate a much saner schema, without those ugly composite keys?

Comment: If you created the schema then use revers engineering to generate entities